# Instantiate an object without giving parameter

Tags: rust

I am implementing a BST with rust, and I have a BSTNode which is the struct with all the functions.
I wanted to instantiate an object in main without providing a value, but I have to because the property value(i32) under BSTNode is not optional.
I tried making it optional, but it requires me to add Some() when I pass a value with any of the methods from the main fn, which looks odd.

```
pub struct BSTNode {
    pub value: Option<i32>,
    pub left: Option<Box<BSTNode>>,
    pub right: Option<Box<BSTNode>>,
}
```

The Instantiate fn:

```
  pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            value: None,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        }
    }
```

Is there an elegant way to instantiate a BSTNode and keeping the root value empty, without having to deal with Option?

What I want to achieve:

```
let mut root = BST::BSTNode::new();
//and then insert into it the values I choose.
root.insert(4)
root.insert(3)
....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A useful pattern when designing a tree type is to make the “public” (or at least the usually-used) type of your tree be the one that *might contain a node* rather than one that *definitely is a node*. For example,

```rust
pub struct BST {
    node: Option<Box<BSTNode>>,
}

struct BSTNode {
    value: i32,
    left: BST,
    right: BST,
}
```

This way, a value of type `BST` can contain any number of values, including none.

Or, you could define it as a single enum:

```rust
pub enum BST {
    Empty,
    Node {
        value: i32,
        left: Box<BST>,
        right: Box<BST>,
    }
}
```

This is the simplest data structure that will work, but it has the disadvantage of allocating a `Box` for every `Empty` leaf. If you rearrange things to avoid that, then you'll end up back at `Option` or a 2-variant enum equivalent to `Option`. So, I'd recommend the first version I showed, which only has as many `Box`es as `value`s.